# How to force certain strings start with a new line using Java regex?

Tags: java, regex

Here is the `String details`

```
String details;
System.out.println(details); // gives the following :

                                "Address: 100 Main Street
                                City: CHICAGO            State: IL       Zip: 624324
                                Department ID: 890840809 ........
                               ........................  "
```

I need to transform it so that `State` and `Zip` start from a new line

```
Address: 100 Main Street
City: CHICAGO            
State: IL       
Zip: 624324
Department ID: 890840809 ........
```

Here is what i tried

```
try {details = details.replaceAll(" State:.*", "\nState:.*"); 
} catch (Exception e) {}
try {details = details.replaceAll(" Zip:.*", "\nZip:.*"); 
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: It does not change anything. Stays the same

Comment: Remove the .* and simply replace " State:" with "\nState:".

Comment: @jaco0646 That means you don't actually need a RE as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right, you need minor modifications:

```
try {details = details.replaceAll(" State:(.*)", "\nState:$1");
                                          ^^^^            ^^ 
} catch (Exception e) {}
try {details = details.replaceAll(" Zip:(.*)", "\nZip:$1");
                                        ^^^^          ^^
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Notice the changes, you need to capture the values using capturing groups `()` so you can use them in the replacement string via `$1`.

Here is a [Regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kM4aN4) using PHP but the concepts are the same, notice how everything works fine now.